# Apache Kafka cannot start multiple instances on same local machine

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, streaming

I am trying to set up Apache Kafka on my local machine to try it out following this official guide: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart.

However, when I tried to start multiple servers, I keep getting the error: "kafka.common.InconsistentBrokerIdException: Configured broker.id 2 doesn't match stored broker.id 0 in meta.properties. If you moved your data, make sure your configured broker.id matches. If you intend to create a new broker, you should remove all data in your data directories (log.dirs)"

I set the parameters exactly following the guide like:

```
broker.id=1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093
log.dir=/tmp/kafka-logs-1
```

I don't quite get it why it's incorrect. I have searched on other sites that they mentioned I need to fix something in meta.properties or log.dirs whatever, but none of these files or directories appear to exist on my computer. Please help me out thx!

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3091

Comment: Each Kafka server needs a unique broker.id (I.e. 1, 2, or 3), listeners port (I.e. 9093, 9094, 9095), and log.dir (/tmp/kafka-logs-1, /tmp/kafka-logs-2, and /tmp/kafka-logs-3)

Comment: Yeah I made 3 servers unique from each other, but the error still persists

Comment: @TalAvissar Do you mean I need to pull the request to fix the error? I downloaded the latest Kafka about 3 days ago

Comment: @HansJespersen I did those to set unique broker.id, listener port and log.dir. However, my question is for the error of broker.id doesn't match. Besides, I could not even find the directory /tmp and I dont have a meta.properties.

Comment: Thanks guys I solved the issue by change those variables at their position. Previously I set the three parameters at the beginning and I just realized that log.dir was set in the end of the file again by default, which causes the log directory to be kafka-logs instead of kafka-logs-1.

Answer (score 6):

I solved the issue by myself by changing those variables in server-1.properties at their original position. Previously I set the three parameters at the beginning of server-1.properties at broker.id section. However the *.properties file is actually very long and log.dir was set in its own section at the end of the file by default to be kafka-logs, which would override my changes at the beginning and cause the errors, because in directory /tmp/kafka-logs the meta.properties has broker.id 0, corresponding to the default server.properties set up. We must have log directory to be kafka-logs-1 so that the meta.properties is also unique for the broker.

By the way, it took me a long time to find out where kafka-logs locates. It locates at root/tmp, rather than inside the folder where kafka library locates. We should type cd /tmp to check it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the Broker.id You set that to 1 but when we add the another server it will increment the id from 0 to 1 directly. so thats why give any other integer number which is not closer to the existing server id